Apache ECharts: Apply visualMap horizontally on area line chart
I implemented the following bar chart that uses a visualMap to apply different gradients of temperature to visualise the degree:

Apache ECharts bar chart implementation (example data)
It is not a smooth presentation caused by lined up bars, so I'd like to implement the same chart as a line chart with a areaStyle. Unfortunately, I can't find any configuration that applies the same behaviour to the created area below the line:

Apache ECharts line chart implementation (example data)
It's much smoother with a line chart but the visualMap applies the color range vertically to the areaStyle in a line chart.
I played a lot with the configuration of line chart to apply the same behaviour but can't find a way to have the identical behaviour of the color mapping along the x-axis.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance!
